# Trying to get div to stick to the side of another centered div and in a fixed position

Tags: html, css

I know this may seem pretty stupid to some of you but I have a "page" div that is centered in the body using auto margins and I am trying to place a small rectangular div to the right side of it like the picture below and have this rectangle fixed in position so it scrolls with the page. any help would be appreciated

Here is a pic of what I am trying to do:

[image]

http://postimg.org/image/ixsgz3n2x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it, is by using `position: fixed` for fixed side elements and placing them inside page container. Then you can move them to the right by setting their margin-left to container width:

```
.main {
    /* page container ... */
    position: relative;
}
.main .side {
    /* side elements ... */
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 410px; /* width of the .main */
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7xyb5g2o/